# running micronaut 1.3.3 try to create simple app getting hibernate error

Tags: hibernate, gradle, groovy, micronaut, micronaut-data

I accidently put hbm2ddl.auto to true. now i can't get rid of it. I changed properties in application.properties file no luck.

```
22:20:14.166 [main] ERROR io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Bean definition [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type [org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateDatastore]: Unrecognized legacy `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` value : `true`
```

Comment: Clean the project, search for the offending keys in the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

> I accidently put hbm2ddl.auto to true. now i can't get rid of it. I
>   changed properties in application.properties file no luck.

I can't reproduce that.  If you can share a project which demonstrates the problem, please file an issue at https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues and we can address that.

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: not sure, what was issue but it is working now. Thanks